# How to get an isolated value from an array using JavaScript map?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I execute the below script, I get an array of values; how to get the value '3' separately out of an array. I use JS map here.

```
function value() { 
 return dataLayer.map(function(item, index) 
 { 
   return (item.event == 'impressionOnScroll' ? index : false);  
 }) 
}; 
value();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. use `Array#filter` to get only the `number-ish` values.

```js
var arr = [false, false, false, 3, false];
    console.log(arr.filter(Number));
    
    //or
    //this will work also for 0
    console.log(arr.filter(v => typeof v == 'number'));
```

Comment: What if the value is `0`?

Comment: function value() { return dataLayer.map(function(item, index) { return (item.event == 'impressionOnScroll' ? index : false);  }) }; parseInt(value().filter(Number));

Comment: The above helped me :) Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @lonesomeday Agreed! Edited my post.

Comment: @PrashanthSams No problem! (:

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) runs a function against every value in an array. If you return a truthy value from the array, it is kept. Otherwise, it is discarded.

Here you should check to see if the value is not false:

```
function value() { 
 return dataLayer.map(function(item, index) 
 { 
   return (item.event == 'impressionOnScroll' ? index : false);  
 }).filter(value => value !== false); 
};
```